# Are there automatic field naming transformations (conventions) in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application with SQL Server. I do my best to write good code by using built in elegance and efficiency.

However, in the database I prefer to further naming in underscore_case, like `id_item_something`. On the C# code side, everything is CamelCase, like `IdItemSomething`.

Are there some magic transformation that could be configured for not having to write a lot of `...ToTable().Property(...).HasColumnName(...)`? Is the `DefaultControllerFactory` the right place to look at?

I have seen such transformations in the JavaScript-jQuery-CSS domain ("background-color" is addressed by "backgroundColor"), and in ASP.NET there is at least the `PluralizingTableNameConvention`.

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework v6 or newer with a code-first approach, you can define your own *custom conventions*, e.g. to map a database column called `id_item_something` to a .NET object field called `IdItemSomething`. [Read more about custom conventions in EF6 here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the edit. This is exactly what I need. If you write your comment as answer, I can mark it as the correct one.